# How to migrate from @aws-cdk/aws-lambda-nodejs to aws cdk v2?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I see that @aws-cdk/aws-lambda-nodejs is outdated

> AWS CDK v1 has reached End-of-Support on 2023-06-01. This package is
> no longer being updated, and users should migrate to AWS CDK v2.
>
> For more information on how to migrate, see the Migrating to AWS CDK
> v2 guide.

It was doing good job with packaging dependancies but what we do now to deploy lambda with dependancies?
I can not find a good example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CDK v2 is at feature parity with v1. See the [migration guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda_nodejs-readme.html) on how to change the imports and packages.

[aws_lambda_nodejs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda_nodejs-readme.html) is the v2 version of what you mention.